# Can I change font type without changing size of JPanels and JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fonts

Everytime I change the font type of the JLabels, JTextAreas, JRadioButtons, etc. in my program it changes the size of the panels that all of these things are in and I have to pack() the frame to make them all fit again which changes the size of the main frame which I obviously do not want. Is there a way to change the font type without changing the size of anything else?

Comment: When a property of a component is changed the component is revalidated because this may cause the preferred size of the comoponent to change. This in turn invokes the layout manager to make sure components are still displayed correctly. So this is a necessary step and should not be avoided. You need to redesign your screen to allow for size changes, maybe by using a scroll pane?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily, the default size of a JLabel, JTextArea etc. is delegated to the "look and feel", this determines the size using the font metrics of the font, the size and the text.

Thefore bigger font, bigger buttons.

I'd advise you to just accept this, and use a layout manager that deals with the nicely...

i.e. don't assume precise layout, instead use something grid-based with enough free-space so that font size can vary.

If you're still desperate to do this you could override the preferred size of the controls with the following, although this pre-supposes you're using a layout manager that respects these hints.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTextField small = new JTextField("small");
    JTextField big = new JTextField("big");
    big.setFont(big.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 40));
    big.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(123, 20));
    big.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(123, 20));
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(small);
    frame.add(big);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```